# Angular HttpClient returns an error in Safari iOS but works on desktop

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I'm using Angular 5.2.2 and CLI 1.6.5, I have a component with method

```js
getRecentMattersForUser(userId: string) {
    this.matterService.getRecentMattersForUser(userId)
        .subscribe(matters => {
        this.matters = matters;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Service

```js
getRecentMattersForUser(userId: string): Observable<Matter[]> {
    const matterService = environment.serviceBaseUrl + '/Matters?requestFor=' + userId;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http.get<Matter[]>(matterService, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

On my desktop this lists matters nicely with an `*ngFor` but in Safari on iOS errorMessage prints:

> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

What's the difference?

I used to use the old `Http` (instead of `HttpClient`) like so

```js
private options = new RequestOptions({ 'withCredentials': true });

getRecentMattersForUser(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    const matterService = environment.serviceBaseUrl + '/Matters?requestFor=' + userId;

    return this.http.get(matterService, this.options)
        .map(this.extractData);
}
```

Which still works.

Any ideas?

Comment: you might need to upgrade es6-shim : https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim. Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901352/angular-2-login-not-working-in-safari-and-firefox

Comment: Removed setting the header and it started working in Safari as well, will have to read up on the doco again and see what I've missed in the later updates.

Comment: Did you find a fix ? Thank you

Comment: Yeah I just removed setting the header with content-type so in the example above:     return this.http.get<Matter[]>(matterService, {
      withCredentials: true
    }); Still need to set the content-type for http post if I remember correctly, don't have access to that source anymore.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557390/angular-4-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error